# Como identificar quando alguém estiver fazendo um upload na página?

Tags: javascript

Preciso atualizar a página a cada 5 minutos, mas tenho um formulário para envio de arquivos na página e geralmente são arquivos grandes.

Tem alguma forma de identificar quando alguém estiver fazendo upload de um arquivo com Javascript?

Código Javascript:

```
setTimeout('location.reload();', 5000);
```

Comment: Como você está atualizando a página? Com `meta` ou javascript?

Comment: editei a pergunta, estou usando Javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se o *upload* estiver a ser realizado via *POST* do formulário, a página faz *refresh* para enviar os dados.

Se o *upload* estiver a ser realizado via *Ajax*, podes utilizar uma variável global para controlar o estado do upload:

```
var variavelGlobalControloUpload;

function minhaFuncaoUpload() {

    // upload começou, dar a conhecer à variavel de controlo
    variavelGlobalControloUpload = 'a carregar';
}

function atualizaPagina () {

   // Verifica se não está a carregar
   if (variavelGlobalControloUpload != 'a carregar') {

     // codigo para atualizar a pagina aqui!
   }
}
```

**Nota:** Isto é um conceito, deverás adaptar o mesmo à tua realidade.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você esteja ciente da baixa confiabilidade de uma condição feita exclusivamente em JavaScript, você pode executar algo no Evento onChange() do campo de upload:

Com jQuery

```
$('#inputfileID').change(function(){
    alert( 'Something...' );
})​
```

Sem ela, porém *inline*:

```
<input type="file" name="whatever" onchange="alert( 'Something...' );" />
```